# Passing serialport data data in a buffer/variable in C++

Tags: c++, windows, serial-port

I have data from serial port from 3 sensor I send in the format

```
sensor0,sensor1,sensor2
```

I use this program:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <sstream>
 #include <Windows.h>
 #include "SerialClass.h"

 char buffer[25];
 using namespace std;

 int i;
 int main()
   {
  Serial oSerial("COM8:");

  oSerial.WriteData("1",1);
       Sleep(100);
       oSerial.ReadData(buffer,25);
string str = buffer;
string word;
stringstream stream(str);

while( getline(stream, word, ',') ) 
    cout <<word << "\n";



Sleep (10000);
   }
```

and the result is:

```
 sensor0
 sensor1
 sensor2
```

I want the result of the data is in a buffer/variable so the result will look like

```
y1=sensor0
y2=sensor1
y3=sensor2
```

How can I change the code so the result is just like that.

Comment: Your question is Windows specific and should be tagged as such

Answer (score 0):

In the code fragment:

```
int count = 1;
while( getline(stream, word, ',') ) 
{
   cout<<"y"<<count<<"="<<word<< "\n";
   count++;
}
```

Comment: If I use that code, I am afraid I can modify the value of the data

Comment: if I use char data[15]; and put data[i]=word, error is occur, because  std::string can not convert to char*